# Django wont display my comments on template

Tags: django, django-models, django-comments

I've tried to implement the comments within the html page after creating them in my models and I have migrated them but they still wont appear within the page although when I add a comment from the admin side of the website the add comment button I added in before the else statement in the html disappears, which means that it isn't empty but the comments still wont show?

Models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
 category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=TRUE,blank=TRUE)
 image=models.ImageField(null=False,blank=False)
 description= models.TextField()

 def __str__(self):
    return self.description

class Comment(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 text = models.TextField()
 date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.user.user.username + ': ' +   self.text
```

and then here is the Html portion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge'>
 <title>Photo</title>
 <meta name='viewport' content='width-device-width, initial-scale=1'>

 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
    1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

<body class="m-5">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="{% url 'Clinician' %}" class="btn btn-dark my-3">Go Back</a>
            <div style="height: 90vh;">
                <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" 
                    src="{{photo.image.url}}">
                <p>
                  {{photo.description}}
                </p>

                 <h4>Comments...</h4>

                 {% if not photo.comments.all %}
                     No Comments Yet...<a href="#">
                         add one
                     </a>
                 {% else %}
                     {% for comment in photo.comment.all %}
                         <strong>
                          
                             {{ comment.date }}
                         </strong>
                         <br/>
                         {{ comment.text }}
                     {% endfor %}
                 {% endif %}
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you share your `views.py` file as well? It's hard to detect the problem without seeing context

Comment: the views.py dosent have anything to do with the comments now showing up as the tutorials I have watched and in my views.py there is nothing that links to these things

Comment: `{% for comment in photo.comment.all %}` See it? Typo - should be `comments.all`

Comment: yup i got it thank you so much